# Which convergence test works best for $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\log(n)\sqrt{n}}{n^2}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\log(n)\sqrt{n}}{n^2}$

First of all, I did the term test, which turned out inconclusive:

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\log(n)\sqrt{n}}{n^2} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\log(n)}{n^\frac{3}{2}} = 0$

Then, d'Alembert's and Cauchy's criterion, which both gave a complicated equation, so I suspected there must be an easier way.
I don't know if I can use the Integral test, because the function doesn't look like it's decreasing in <1,inf)
[image]

Which of the converge tests would be the most reasonable in this case?

Comment: Compare to $\sum \frac{1}{n^{1.1}}$ for example and note that $\log n/n^{3/2} \leq 1/n^{1.1}$ for all large $n$ (other $n$ are only a finite sum, so don't affect convergence either way).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall that for any $a>0$

$$\frac{\log n}{n^a} \to 0$$

therefore the given series converges by [limit comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test) with $\frac{1}{n^c}$ with $1<c<\frac32$.

Answer (score 3):

$\log n=3 \log n^{1/3} <3n^{1/3}$.  Use comparision test.

Comment: thank you, makes a lot of sense

Comment: Elegant  ( +1 ).